# WSDL WebService

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I need comunicating using java with a WebService that uses the WSDL technology.
I tried some libraries but with no success, thus, I decided to do it manually.

My plan is getting a `.xml` which uses the comunication (filtering with fiddler for example) and copy it manually building a string. So the .`xml` will be ok. Do I need to take care of anything else?

Do I have to do any more? Http request, response?

I wouldn't like to create all the structure for the xml and after that, find that I can't continue the comunication.

Thanks

Comment: The Axis2 framework makes web service clients automagically.  And there are others as well.  No need to build your own parser if you don't really want to.

Answer (score 2):

Java comes with a complete API for XML Web Services, this is JAX-WS. (lot of documentation available with a simple serach with google)

it allows developers to build a working client with very little effort starting from a WSDL file (seems your case)

I really discourage you to build the client by yourself. You should care about SOAP message building, message sending, response parsing and so on.